# How to concatenate numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How to concatenate numpy array?

I want to concatenate all numpy arrays.

for example, there are some  numpy array as below

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array([4,5,6])
c = numpy.array([7,8,9])
```

To concatenate them all.

we need a extra empty variable.

```
tot = numpy.concatenate(tot, a)
tot = numpy.concatenate(tot, b)
tot = numpy.concatenate(tot, c)
```

how to declare tot empty variable ? (if there are too many arrays?)

Comment: What do you expect?  `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` or `[1,2,3,4,5...]`.?  `concatenate` accepts a list of arrays - but pay close attention to your dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You need them in a tuple:

```
>>> tot = numpy.concatenate((a,b,c))
>>> tot
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but would like to propose it of curiosity

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array([4,5,6])
c = numpy.array([7,8,9])

d = numpy.array(list(a)+list(b)+list(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tot = np.concatenate([a,b,c], axis=0)
```

Read the [Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)